# Bash script to delete files older than x days within a subdirectory tree

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder `/data` and inside there I have many folders.. I want to remove the contents of these directories after 30 days of creation, but not the directory itself.

So my path would be `/data/dirname/files` or `/data/dirname/anotherdir/files`.

The first dirname needs to be saved since it is shared via FTP.

When the script or command is done I guess crontabbing it would be a good idea, right?

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can recursively list all regular files under `\data` that were last modified 30 days ago with

```
find /data -type f -mtime +30 -ls
```

But you have to note that `mtime` isn't necessarily the time of creation. I don't think that it's possible to check for time of creation. You just have `ctime`, `atime` and `mtime` to check for.

If you want to delete those files you can invoke a similar command

```
find /data -type f -mtime +30 -delete
```

Of course you can add this command to your `crontab` file.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my suggestion:

`find /data -type f -a -ctime +30 -print0 | xargs --no-run-if-empty -0 rm -f`

`find /data -type l -a -ctime +30 -print0 | xargs --no-run-if-empty -0 rm -f`

`find /data -type d -mindepth 1 -print0  | xargs --no-run-if-empty -0 rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty`

It's a bit more elaborate, but it cleans up files, symlinks and empty directories. The --no-run-if-empty, -f and --ignore-fail-on-non-empty options prevent mails from your cronjob in case something can't be cleaned up.

I'm using ctime; using mtime has the disadvantage that if you unpack a zip or tar file, dates will mostly be in the past, causing the files to disappear after just one day. Empty directories are removed immediately, though.

Comment: WHy don't you just run this as a single `find` command without specifying `-type`? That way you can do files links and directories in one fell swoop and pass them to `rm -rf`.

Comment: Because that will delete directories with content, regardless of the age of the files in it...

Comment: True, but the age of the directory should be the same as its newest file.

Comment: That's a dangerous assumption. Plus, any file removal/addition in a directory will also change it ctime stamp, causing the empty directory to linger for another 30 days. So, for example, a 4-level deep directory will take 120 days to get cleaned up completely. That script comes from experience :)